# Magento Magmi: When updating, is the first column in the csv used as the foreign key?

Tags: magento, magmi

I usually update based on SKU... but, I need to change the SKUs this time. Heh, so I couldn't find any definitive answer in the wiki, but how does magmi choose the csv column to use as the foreign key when doing updates? I assume it is the first column, but would rather not guess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the columns does not matter.  Magmi converts the column name into a column index, then processes the data for those columns row by row.

The skus are used to associate the item in the CSV with an existing item in Magento.  Changing the sku in the Magmi datasource would cause that item to be uploaded as a new item.

If you're wanting to change the skus, I would recommend deleting the old items, changing the skus, then uploading the new ones.

Comment: After accepting this answer, I am not sure it is correct. It appears that the [Value Replacer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Value_Replacer) Plugin can effectively change skus. Granted, the SKU column with the original value is still required.